# Hosting simple NPM local server on GitHub gh-pages?

Tags: javascript, github, server

Is it possible to currently host local served content to gh-pages that isn't a framework?

Just simple html, css, and JS files along with API calls.

Currently using a npm package `http-server` for a simple server.

- I attempted using `npm gh-pages`, however because I am not using a framework, I don't have a build option. Even using the default `npm run-script build` does not exist. Even so, I read that `build` is required for C/C++ bindings that causes a requirement for a build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gh-pages only serves static content, it doesn't allow server-side hosting.

This is no problem:

> simple html, css, and JS files

but this

> along with API calls.

is not possible unless you do everything through requests to external servers.

Comment: I see. I thought I'd give this question a shot due to having the ability of uploading 2 front-end React applications with API calls through ```gh-pages``` for npm. I appreciate your response, thank you.